# {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing required parameter: code"}curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: curl, oauth

I'm sending this curl request and it includes the code but I'm receiving an error missing required parametter:code

```
curl -X POST https://xxxxx.auth0.com/oauth/token \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code \
  -d redirect_uri=https://example-app.com/redirect \
  -d client_id=xxxxxxxx \
  -d client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx \ 
  -d code_verifier=xxxxxxxxxx \
  -d code=xxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

the URL needs to go last and it is best to include the data in double quotes to prevent interference with the shell, so:

```
curl -X POST \
  -d "grant_type=authorization_code" \
  -d "redirect_uri=https://example-app.com/redirect" \
  -d "client_id=xxxxxxxx" \
  -d "client_secret=xxxxxxxxxx" \ 
  -d "code_verifier=xxxxxxxxxx" \
  -d "code=xxxxxxxxxx" \
  https://xxxxx.auth0.com/oauth/token
```

Comment: Using this format shows the following error: curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Comment: most probably your values contain unsafe characters, please try with double quotes as edited